# Как писали «Нью-Йорк» до реформы 1918 года?

Tags: ономастика, названия, старая-орфография, реформа

На форуме  был вопрос на эту тему и был дан ответ с таким текстом:

English names in yo, ye etc. (and names borrowed through English, especially Japanese ones) were traditionally written using iо, iе in Russian: Iоркъ, Нью-Iоркъ, Iорикъ; Iокогама, Iеддо, iенъ etc, although йо was used occasionally as well.

After the orthography reform of 1918, the English names changed the first letter to й (Йорк, Йорик) while the traditional Japanese ones retained the now uniform и: иена, Иокогама.

Это машинный перевод:

Английские имена в yo, ye и т. д. (и имен заимствовано через английский, особенно японские) были традиционно написаны с использованием io, т. е. по-русски: **Iоркъ, Нью-Iоркъ, Iорикъ;** Iokorama, Ieggo, iенъ и т. д. После орфографической реформы 1918 года **английские имена поменяла первую букву на й (Йорк, Йорик)** в то время как традиционные японские сохранил теперь униформа и: иена, Иокогама.

[https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/Почему-Йорк-а-не-Ёрк](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%81%D1%80%D0%BA)

Но мне попалась **книга 1852 года в старой орфографии**, где было написано **Нью-Йоркъ.** http://ino-lit.ru/lit/text/1071/17373/Dickens/amerikanskie-ocherki-glava-oldorfo.htm

Вся ли информация на эту тему в приведенной статье на форуме изложена верно?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (что осталось непонятным)

В 1918 году  в ходе реформы из алфавита была исключена буква  І («и десятеричное»); вместо нее стала  употребляться, буква  И.

Если до реформы существовали написания **Іо** или парные написания **Іо/йо**,  то они, вероятно,   должны были замениться написаниями  **ио или йо.** Этот вопрос как-то решался  на официальном уровне в ходе реформы или после нее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вряд ли есть смысл тратить время на обсуждение RSE-ответа, поскольку автор того ответа не приводит никаких источников информации в пользу своей странной версии.

[Скан-копии страниц](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_ru&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1138&bih=506&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899%2Clr%3Alang_1ru&tbm=bks&ei=lNsBYLKjN-yWjgae0ZDwCA&q=%22%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%22%20OR%20%22%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%8A%22%20-%22New-York%22&oq=%22%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%22%20OR%20%22%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%8A%22%20-%22New-York%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6913.14374.0.14967.14.14.0.0.0.0.182.1558.2j12.14.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.O7cv1YP46ks) дореволюционных изданий в гугло-книгах дают примерно поровну вариантов каждого написания (сформировать правильный гугл-запрос оказалось не так просто).

Написание тогда ещё не было окончательно устоявшимся, но в пользу **Й**-варианта можно также процитировать "Русское правописание" Я.К. Грота, 1894:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но вот никто не говорит о том, что написание   ЙО характерно для ударного слога, где такую фонетику обозначает в современных словах  буква Ё. А   слова Иосиф, Иордан имеют сейчас другое произношение. А во времена Грота как было?

Comment: @Sharon Я не знаю. Грот рассматривает ещё восходящие и нисходящие дифтонги с полугласными, "йотованные" двугласные, диграфы *йо, йа, йу, йэ* ("только в иноязычных словах: майоръ, Йорк"), предлагает ввести термин "облечённые гласные". Сейчас всё это не производит впечатления стройной и завершённой теории.

Comment: @Sharon Иосиф сейчас имеет другое произношение, но Йордан Йовчев уже современная транскрипция.

Answer (score 4):

Это **не** старая орфография, а какая-то пародия, или, как бы сказала молодежь, "закос" под неё.

Нужно смотреть на оригинал книги, а не чью-то "обработку". В Google Books оригинал этой книги мне найти не удалось, к сожалению.

Вот фрагмент другой книги (1892 года) о Диккенсе и его путешествии в Америку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что слова *здесь*, *на улице*, *в Нью-Iорке* и др. пишутся через "ять". В тексте же по вашей ссылке *здесь* через "е", и вообще ни одного "ять" я, бегло пробежав глазами, не встретил (а это как раз та буква, которая сразу бросается в глаза).

Что совершенно, разумеется, не доказывает, что никто никогда не писал *Нью-Йорк* через *й* в те времена, но данный источник доказательством не является.

Comment: *Это не старая орфография, а какая-то пародия, или, как бы сказала молодежь, "закос" под неё* - это текст, полученый машинным переводом из ново в старую. Со всеми сопутсвующими ляпами.

Comment: @behemothus Да, я так и подумал. Наверное, где-то на этом сайте это даже упомянуто, но искать лень.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но всё-таки действительно в указанных именах собственных не употребляли букву Й до 1918 года? И всё ли верно в статье, нет ошибок?

Comment: Под статьёй вы что имеете в виду? Отрывок из ответа пользователя @Quassnoi на russian.stackexchange.com? *действительно в указанных именах собственных не употребляли букву Й до 1918 года?* - думаю, употребляли изредка. Тот же Google Books дает такие примеры, но дело в том, что все их надо проверять (интернет полон мусора, верить ничему нельзя), а мне сейчас просто некогда.

Comment: Хорошо, еще раз спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 3):

> Как писали «Нью-Йорк» до реформы 1918 года?

Как писали? По-разному.

**Новый Йоркъ** —

— в книге "Детское чтение для сердца и разума" 1787 года изд.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое же написание — и в книге "Новейшее повествовательное землеописание всех четырех частей света" (1795), и у Карамзина в "Письмах русского путешественника" (1793).

**Новый-Йоркъ** —

— у Толстого в "Войне и мире". См. изд. 1880 года:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нью-Йоркъ** —

— см., к примеру, книгу Фролова Н.Г. "Исправительные тюрьмы в Швейцарии" изд. 1847 года:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нью-Iоркъ** —

— Павленков Флорентий Федорович "Энциклопедический словарь", 1910:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

— Нечаев, Александр Павлович "По морю и суше : Геогр. хрестоматия для чтения в шк. и дома", 1909:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чаще до 1918 года употреблялось написание с "Й".

Из "Русской грамматики" Александра Востокова изд. 1859 г.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написание с "Й" поддерживал и Грот, ссылку но которого уже давали в этой теме.

Comment: Слава, Ваша большая изыскательская работа заслуживает комплиментов!

Answer (score 0):

@Sharon

> но вот никто не говорит о том, что написание ЙО характерно для
> ударного слога, где такую фонетику обозначает в современных словах
> буква Ё.

Я думаю, что потому и не говорят, что это слишком обязывающее утверждение.
Напротив, именно для Ё в иноязычных словах чаще используовалось IO - просто таких слов вообще крайне мало.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.